# How to add a settings page to my mobile android app?

Tags: android, button

So I'm new to android development. I have made a digital clock and just want to know how I could make a button that leads to a settings page(a completely seperate page).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to go to bluetooth settings on click of button.Like this you can go to any settings page by just calling  **android.provider.Settings.(ACTION NAME)**

Different action names are:
**ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS**

**ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS**, etc.

```
buttonBluetoothSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS));

            }
        });
```